# How to rip long planks without causing them to deform?

Tags: wood, wood-movement

I may want to rip down a stain-grade pine 1x5 plank to about 3-3/4 width.  I have a number of these planks that have been sitting indoors for over a month so any movement should have settled already.  I'm making door jambs so I need these to be straight.  I could take a plank, straighten one edge with a power planer, then run it through my table saw but I'm concerned that it will crook after it is cut and if not immediately then possibly way down the road after it's been installed.

How can I narrow down a plank without it becoming crooked or otherwise deformed?  Alternatively, would I be better off taking a 1x4 and gluing on a narrow strip to make it wider?

Comment: Coming at this from a slightly different angle than the two good Answers you've gotten so far, is there any particular reason you *expect* these are going to crook? While a month isn't really enough time for wood to have come to a new equilibrium stain-grade pine is nothing like 2x stuff. I presume your boards are largely straight-grained and completely or mostly without knots? That's the kind of wood that tends not to have a tendency to warp unusually (although bowing or some slight cupping can still happen, but from a completely different cause).

Comment: Re. *after installation*, if installed correctly crook should be basically impossible, unless the fasteners come loose.

Comment: @Graphus.  I got 1x5s before and ripped them in half down the middle full length and a significant number crooked.  That was last year.  I recently found a piece of one of those and it's warped even more since.  Looks like a bow.  These are stain-grain pine so they are mostly free of knots but they're not that straight either because they warped already or just weren't cut all that straight.  Delivered from a lumber yard, don't know how they store them or who makes them.

Comment: @Graphus re after installation: I'm fastening a 75" jamb in 3-4 places, maybe 5 if i'm trying to straighten out a bend.  It could still crook between the shimmed spots.  Don't think the casing would hold it in place.  The door would probably still close but it would look ugly.  Anyway, I would rather do 1 thing wrong instead of 2.

Comment: I think some test cuts are in order to see what you're dealing with; assuming the worst certainly helps cushion the blow if the wood disappoints, but maybe it'll surprise you. Course there's no guarantee some boards will be good, others bad. Anyhoo, if you do find the wood is prone to crook and you can stomach the waste one method is to get down to dimension in steps, working in from both edges. It means you get at most laths/shims from the 1x5s, possibly nothing but sawdust, but by not making a significant rip cut into two significant boards there's a better chance the keeper piece [contd]

Comment: ends up straight (because of slow release of tension). There's another route to consider for the future IF you're set up for significant processing of wood and that's starting from 1x10s or 1x12s. Most are flat-sawn, with significant curvature in the growth rings, but that means towards both edges the wood is in effect rift- or quarter-sawn. Ripping down and glueing up can give a fair yield of RS or QS SYP that's largely knot free, at a fraction of the normal cost. But the lead time means this isn't viable now, you want to give the wood *at least* a couple of months to acclimate, pref. longer.

Answer (score 3):

Any piece of wood *could* warp at any time between now and `x` time in the future. If you wait to use it until you think the wood won't warp on you, then you should probably find a different hobby/profession to fill your time because you're going to be waiting a *long* time.

The drier the wood is the less likely it is to warp. Get yourself a moisture meter and look up info on what the idea moisture level is for your pine. Wait until the wood is that dry to minimize the likelihood of it warping.

On the other hand, since the wood has been sitting inside (presumably in the same indoor atmosphere where it will be installed - inside my garage is different than inside my house, for example), it's probably dry enough and you shouldn't worry about it. For example, I live in a house built in the 1890s. I've got wide pine trim in many parts of it, and none of it seems to have warped in over 100 years.

Your level of worry  is entirely up to you, but I'm guessing you have nothing significant to worry about at this point. You *might* have to replace the wood, but it's likely that if it twists when you cut it, no amount of further drying would have prevented it.

Comment: It's always worth bearing in mind that for thicker pieces (and 1" thick is certainly thick enough) interior MC will always be higher than surface moisture levels. Plus of course 1 month isn't nearly enough time for boards to come to a new equilibrium (even with really good storage — stacked in stick, good ventilation ensured) if the conditions from retail storage were very different to the workshop/home. I was literally just reading something last night and the author mentions casually that he bought the wood *six months* in advance to ensure it did have enough time to come to equilibrium O_O

Comment: @Graphus I had a question about building doors earlier.  The wood I used for that was studs from demolished walls in my house.  That was ~70 years old so I felt comfortable ripping it to size and square.  Also much nicer lumber than what I can buy now so didn't want to waste it.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory. yeah they sure don't make studs like they used to! It's not much of an exaggeration to say the 2x material of yesterday is better than most any wood of the same species you can buy today.

Comment: The reason new lumber isn't as great as old lumber is because of the drying process.  it used to be air dried, now kilns super dry it super fast, this causes stress and damage to the internal structure of wood, allowing it to degrade faster.  One reason I have a mill myself...

Comment: I'm planning on building an addition this summer, @bowlturner, can I contract with you for a supply of 2x dimensional lumber? ;) Two more reasons modern framing lumber aren't of the same quality as older: 1) Nominal v actual size 1.5'x3.5" "2x4" vs actual 2"x4" (we've had to make jamb extensions for all our replacement doors & windows). 2) Old growth lumber v new, fast growth lumber. Looking at the lumber in our floor joists, I can see _tiny_ growth rings, while new lumber has wide, superhighway growth rings...

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things that cause wood to 'warp or kink' after it's cut.  This is caused by stresses on the wood, sometimes if the wood is dried really fast and unevenly, there can be stresses added and by cutting it (especially the long way) you are releasing this stress, at least on one side, and will usually bend the opposite way, Planning an edge can even release some of this, if it is there.

The other is naturally stressed wood, usually from a leaning tree or branch, and it can become pretty stable, until you cut it, if this is the case there is nothing you can do but make curved furniture...

Pine generally isn't affected by the 2nd issue and the first I think most manufactures don't make that mistake any more.  So the only thing left is natural moisture movement, which you have little control over and clear straight grained wood generally is pretty stable once it dries and you should have little worry.

On top of that pine tends to either warp and twist right away, or not at all. and it's soft enough that once it's nailed down, it almost never moves, other than the swelling and shrinking of the seasons.

Comment: "make curved furniture..." worth an upvote for sure!

Comment: Yeah, @gnicko, this from the guy who goes by the name "bowlturner". ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach makes sense, but if you're particularly concerned about this wood, I suggest you remove the extra width in two cuts, rather than one.    Joint one edge straight as you suggest, then rip down to within 1/4" or so of your desired width, let the wood settle for a day or two, then if the wood remains straight, rip to final width.    If not rejoint and rip to final dimension.   That shouldn't be necessary for properly dried, reasonably straight-grained pine, but it will take care of any problems that do arise.

As others have said, if dry at installation, pine isn't going to move much at all, beyond normal expansion and contraction, once it's fastened in place.

Comment: Just to reinforce — wood, no matter how wet/dry can have internal stresses that are released when you cut a board. You’ll see it more frequently when you cut down the middle, but even taking an inch off an edge can make a difference.